# Выборка MySQL. Сортировка по тегам

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Добрый день, пользователи! Помогите пожалуйста составить правильный MySQL-запрос. Вопрос мой в следующем:
Есть таблица, в которой хранятся **"теги"** и ничего более.. В другой таблице **"Новости"** есть **поле "tags"**, которое содержит ID введенных мною тегов, например, ***1, 2, 4, 7.***

Я передаю в функцию тег и мне нужно отсортировать все новости с этим тегом.

Не хочу использовать в таблице выборку по полю **"tags"** через **WHERE LIKE "%%"**. Можете помочь и предложить хорошую и правильную альтернативу **без WHERE tags LIKE "%%"**?

Comment: Перепроектировать БД? Т.е. вынести связь "новость-тег" в отдельную табличку.

Недавно в ответах видел упоминание mangoDB(?) - альтернатива реляционным БД. Вроде как упоминали в аналогичном контексте.

И если бы задача стояла поиска по тексту - посоветовал бы что-нибудь типа Sphinx`а, но в данном контексте его применение вряд ли будет оправданным.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал на данный момент **БЕЗ WHERE LIKE "%%"** следующим образом. Если что поправьте меня, если ничем поправить, то может кому-нибудь и пригодиться...

```
SELECT 
    n.id, n.text, n.tags
FROM tags t, news n
WHERE t.name="нужный тег" AND FIND_IN_SET(t.id, n.tags) > 0
```